# Gives an error when i try to build a c++ program

Tags: c++, build

I just started learning c++ and i am having problems building my code. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I if i try to build this, i get the following error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make.exe -j 8 -e -f  Makefile
'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

I was first using code blocks and i got the same error, so i tried switching codelite hoping to fix this problem but i still keep getting the same error. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is nothing to do with code. The error tells you that compiler can not be found.

Comment: read wikipage on [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) and on [`make` software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and on [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)

Comment: Notice that [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), not a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). But [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a C++ [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your compiler isn't pathed correctly.

https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Just create a path to 'mingw32-make.exe'.

After updating the path, you may want to close and reopen your IDE.

If all else fails, just download Visual Studios Community.

Comment: Just tried doing that but i am still getting the same error :(

Comment: You could also prefix `mingw23-make.exe` with it's path (place the entire path and name inside double quotes so that Windows doesn't mistake the '-' as an argument specifier).